# Start at boot time Corosync 2.X + Pacemaker 1.1 cluster (Debian Wheezy)

Tags: debian, cluster-computing, pacemaker, runlevel

I am having what seems an easy problem to solve, but I don't know the correct way to solve it.

I've been googling for a solution for almost a week without luck.
(All I found was [this](http://people.adams.edu/~cdmiller/posts/Pacemaker-Corosync-Ubuntu-Lucid/) but had no clear and clean solution)

I have created a two node cluster NOT FOR PRODUCTION with the following configuration on both nodes:

- Debian Wheezy 7.7
- Corosync v2.3.4
- Pacemaker v1.1.12
- Libqb v0.17.1
- Cluster-glue v1.0.12
- Resource-agents v3.9.6
- crmsh v2.1.0

I've installed the cluster software from source following [this guide](http://clusterlabs.org/wiki/Compiling_on_Debian) to compile cluster softwares on Debian

Before installing I made sure there were no older corosync or pacemaker dependencies.

After the installation I configured my cluster editing the file (on both nodes) corosync.conf and creating and copying the authkey

```
# Please read the corosync.conf.5 manual page
totem {
        version: 2

#       crypto_cipher: none
#       crypto_hash: none
        secauth: off
        cluster_name: my-cluster
#       interface {
#               ringnumber: 0
#               bindnetaddr: 10.16.2.0
#               mcastport: 5405
#               ttl: 1
#       }
        transport: udpu
}

logging {
        fileline: off
        to_logfile: yes
        to_syslog: yes
        logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
        debug: off
        timestamp: on
        logger_subsys {
                subsys: QUORUM
                debug: off
        }
}

nodelist {
        node {
                ring0_addr: 10.16.2.50
                name: pc1
                nodeid: 1
        }

        node {
                ring0_addr: 10.16.2.51
                name: pc2
                nodeid: 2
        }
}

quorum {
        # Enable and configure quorum subsystem (default: off)
        # see also corosync.conf.5 and votequorum.5
        provider: corosync_votequorum
        two_node: 1
}
```

I've configured the resources on pacemaker

```
node 1: pc-1
node 2: pc-2
primitive cluster-apache2 apache \
    params configfile="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" httpd="/usr/sbin/apache2" port=80 \
    op monitor interval=10s timeout=60s \
    op start timeout=40s interval=0 \
    op stop timeout=60s interval=0
primitive cluster-ip IPaddr2 \
    params ip=10.16.2.240 cidr_netmask=24 \
    op monitor interval=10s timeout=20s \
    op start timeout=20s interval=0 \
    op stop timeout=20s interval=0
primitive cluster-tftp lsb:tftpd-hpa \
    op monitor interval=30 \
    op start interval=0 timeout=120s \
    op stop interval=0 timeout=120s
colocation my-cluster-dependency inf: cluster-ip cluster-apache2 cluster-tftp
property cib-bootstrap-options: \
    dc-version=1.1.12-561c4cf \
    cluster-infrastructure=corosync \
    stonith-enabled=false \
    cluster-name=my-cluster
```

After all the configuratins I've started both corosync and pacemaker with

```
/etc/init.d/corosync start
/etc/init.d/pacemaker/start
```

The cluster is up and running, but I can't find a way to start the cluster at boot time

```
root@PC:~# crm_mon -1
Last updated: Fri Jun  5 18:05:06 2015
Last change: Mon Jun  1 18:51:57 2015 via cibadmin on pc-1
Stack: corosync
Current DC: pc-1 (1) - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.12-561c4cf
2 Nodes configured
3 Resources configured


Online: [ pc-1 pc-2 ]

 cluster-ip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started pc-1 
 cluster-apache2    (ocf::heartbeat:apache):    Started pc-1 
 cluster-tftp   (lsb:tftpd-hpa):    Started pc-1
```

I've tried adding the init.d scripts to runlevels, but I get no response and no effect on corosync

```
root@PC:~# update-rc.d corosync defaults 
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

and this error on pacemaker

```
root@PC:~# update-rc.d pacemaker defaults 
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: Service corosync has to be enabled to start service pacemaker
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

I've followed the guide on clusterlabs but I can't find a solution for Debian and crmsh 
(on [the official guide](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-pcs/html-single/Clusters_from_Scratch/index.html) they use pcs instead of crmsh, but even with that I could not find the correct procedure to make the cluster run at boot time)

Another info I can add is, I've also tried to use crmsh to start and run the cluster, trying to find a way to make it run at boot time.
If i run crm cluster start (instead of the init.d scripts) corosync and pacemaker start and the cluster starts running, but if i run the command to stop I get this error

```
crm(live)# cluster stop
ERROR: cluster.stop: Failed to stop pacemaker service:
```

What is the correct way to make the cluster run at boot time? 
What daemon must be started and enabled?

Should pacemaker be started by corosync? I've found [this guide](http://blog.clusterlabs.org/blog/2010/introducing-the-pacemaker-master-control-process-for-corosync-based-clusters/) but the parameters mentioned service-name and service-ver don't work in my corosync configuration.

```
service {
    name: pacemaker
    ver: 0
}
```

Hope somebody could help me with this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For 2 nodes active/passive you should disable the quorum.

```
crm configure property no-quorum-policy=ignore
```

The cluster is active as long as the corosync service is active. You don't need to start explicitly pacemaker.
You should have at least this lines about corosync:

```
ls -lR /etc/rc* | grep -E 'corosync|rc'
/etc/rc0.d:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 may 15 17:19 K01corosync -> ../init.d/corosync
/etc/rc1.d:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 may 15 17:19 K01corosync -> ../init.d/corosync
/etc/rc2.d:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 may 15 17:19 S19corosync -> ../init.d/corosync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 dic 17  2013 S99rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local
/etc/rc3.d:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 may 15 17:19 S19corosync -> ../init.d/corosync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 dic 17  2013 S99rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local
/etc/rc4.d:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 may 15 17:19 S19corosync -> ../init.d/corosync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 dic 17  2013 S99rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local
/etc/rc5.d:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 may 15 17:19 S19corosync -> ../init.d/corosync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 dic 17  2013 S99rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local
/etc/rc6.d:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 may 15 17:19 K01corosync -> ../init.d/corosync
/etc/rcS.d:
```

If you don't have this links or similar you should make it manually.

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: I have disabled quorum.
Now I was able to use update-rc.d with corosync and pacemaker (There were no default runlevels specified in the init.d scripts) but pacemaker does not start.
I use pacemaker 1.1.12, and it doesn't get started automatically by corosync...which version do you use?

Comment: I have those symlinks for corosync and alos pacemaker